# Populate an excel workbook using data from another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 1 workbook that has 5 columns:

NAME | DOB | GENDER | AR | FINAL PLAN ISSUED DATE

I am trying to populate the GENDER and FINAL PLAN ISSUES DATEs into a separate workbook that also has the same columns. I have some of the dates etc already, but rather than manually checking one by one ss there a formula / macro that can be used so that workbook 1 will populate the columns if the NAMEs and DOB  in workbook 2 match?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since both workbooks have the same structure you could simply use a VLOOKUP() with a helper column.

[Check Layout and formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEkk3.png)

I put the input and output in the same spreadsheet, but you should be able to do so with separate ones. The first column is a helper column with formula `$A2&$B2` and filled down. Then in the formula in `K2`, I use a `VLOOKUP` to look up the concatenated value of **NAME** and **DOB**. The `COLUMNS` calculates the *distance* between the target columns and Kth column so that you can simply drag the formula to column M and fill down easily.